# icCube - Adding the Title (The header) When export the Chart to Image

Tags: iccube, export-to-image

I need That the header shows when I export the Chart to Image

My Chart is Like This :
[image]

But when I export it to Image it's Without the header

[image]

Can any one help me to fix this , Txs, Marwen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AmChart widget allows you to export only widget's content without box header.

You can achieve needed result with AmChart's [functionality](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/Label).

Just set below code as a value to
 "Edit... > Widget > Advanced Properties > Extra Options"

```
:{"allLabels": [
    {
        "text": "Product Sale",
        "size": 32,
        "bold": true,
        "x": 0,
        "y": 0
    }]}
```

**UPDATE**

If your title overlays the chart you can try to change widget box's height and width along with extending "Extra options" with "marginLeft" and "marginTop" options which allow you to create needed room for chart and it's title:

```
:{"allLabels": [
    {
        "text": "Product Sale",
        "size": 32,
        "bold": true,
        "x": 0,
        "y": 0
    }],
 "marginTop":50,
 "marginLeft":50}
```

[image]